# golang wikitext parser from scratch

Tags: wikitext

I am asked to build a wiki in golang. Some of the editors are familiar with the wikitext, so they want to keep it. I find it's really hard to build a wikitext parser from scratch and there's no open source golang parser. Can anyone give me some suggestion?
I have searched go.pkg, there's no available pkg

Answer (score 0):

You could call an external tool (https://github.com/5j9/wikitextparser) from your go code with https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec, which is probably easier to parse than raw wikitext.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).